# How to fade in/out images with impress.js

Tags: svg, presentation, impress.js

As you can see [in this](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/pautasso/talks/2012/soa-cloud-rest-tcc/rest-tcc.html#/interop-2) example, when you press < RIGHT > key, another images appear over the existing one.

Looking at the source code there is only one image .svg: http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/pautasso/talks/2012/soa-cloud-rest-tcc/img/interop-ws2.svg

How can i get this effect with another image?

Comment: did you figure out how he made this steps in the svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [pull request](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/pull/280) on impress.js, you can simply add a class="substep" in the elements you want to appear after the < RIGHT > key instead of going to next slide.

You can extend your current impress.js just by adding the above patch.

Comment: That pull request is not (yet) merged, so in effect it is fork of mpress.js Check it's demo at http://tehfoo.github.io/impress.js/

Comment: Oh, hai.  That pull request came from my fork of impress.js.  It's just impress.js with substeps and nothing else.  The substep stuff is pretty well documented, hopefully someone else finds it useful.  From comments in my pull request it looks like it will probably never be merged into impress.js for reals.


My fork is here: https://github.com/tehfoo/impress.js